# Sort by multiple keys on MongoDB collection with large document count.

Tags: mongodb

When I want to sort by multiple keys on mongodb, I am running into some problem ,
How do I fix it ??

> db.test.a.count()

78150

> db.test.a.ensureIndex({a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1});
>
> db.test.a.find().sort({a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1});

```
error: {
        "$err" : "too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or speci
fy a smaller limit",
        "code" : 10128
}
```

Comment: Are you running these from the interactive shell?

Comment: which version of MongoDB you are using?

Comment: the syntax looks strange. I would have expected db.test.find().sort({a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1}). What happens when you run db.test.find().limit(10).sort({a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1}).explain() and db.test.find().sort({a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1}).explain()?